# Datagridview To Return Values In Column (To String?)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am trying to pass DataGridView values into string and then to a TextBox. But I don't understand where am I going wrong.

```
int CFee = 0;
int CLAIMAMT = 0;
int requests = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string requests = (dataGridView1.RowCount);
    while (requests.Length < 5)
        requests = "0" + requests;
    textBox2.Text = requests.ToString();
    string  CFee = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CFee"].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        CFee = "0" + CFee;
    while (CFee.Length < 9)
        CFee += "0";
    textBox3.Text = CFee.ToString();
    string  CLAIMAMT = (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CLAIMAMT"].Value);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        CLAIMAMT = "0" + CLAIMAMT;
    while (CLAIMAMT.Length < 10)
        CLAIMAMT += "0";
    textBox4.Text = CLAIMAMT.ToString();
}
```

My required output is this:

```
no of requests = 00002; // 5 characters
court fee = 000006000; // 9 characters
claim amount = 0000020000; // 10 characters
```

If I normally assign values to string like string `requests = "2"`, I get that. But I want to know how to pass values of DataGridView as string. I am getting an error like:

```
A local variable named 'CFee' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'CFee', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else.
```

Comment: what exact functionality you want to achieve from your code posted ?

Comment: I want to get the required output shown  tried various ways but not to luck.I tried the above code it was perfect but was not able  to pass datagrid view values to string like....   `string requests = (dataGridView1.RowCount);`

Comment: Ok. Let's make understanding easy. For 0th row, suppose dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CFee"].Value is 1 then what would be the value of the textBox3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Rename `string CFee` to `string  strCFee` - its conflicting with `int CFee`

Comment: Thanks Acme .. if i rename i got an error like  `'int' does not contain a definition for 'Length' and no extension method 'Length' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You face the same problem with `string CLAIMAMT` - rename it to `string strCLAIMAMT` and then use `strCLAIMAMT.Length` instead of `CLAIMAMT.Length` - Do the same with `requests`.

Comment: I tried to change everything but still errrors .. frustating acme... help me please.. `A local variable named 'i' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'i', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else`

Comment: @preethi -Why in the world are you using same variable names everywhere? Try this out - http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=6756

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CFee"].Value

Comment: Apply `ToString()` - `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CFee"].Value.ToString()`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48587/discussion-between-preethi-and-acme)

Answer (score 0):

You need to rename all of your string variables because even variables with different types cannot have the same name, otherwise the compiler wouldn't know what to do.

And, to use Length, you must first use ToString() to convert what you want.

Concerning the counter variables 'i', they're conflicting with the 'i' already declared at the first for loop. Just give another name to them.

And just another thing: to get your datagridview values you need to [convert to string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before assigning them to string variables:

```
string  strCLAIMAMT = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CLAIMAMT"].Value.ToString();
```